# MediaPlayer info/warning (1, 0)

Tags: android, google-tv

MediaPlayer starts playing music, but in log I found warning messages;

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
mp.start();
```

Warning and Info Log messages:

> 01-14 16:21:41.708: W/MediaPlayer(12434): info/warning (1, 0)
>
> 01-14 16:21:41.708: I/MediaPlayer(12434): Info (1,0)

I did not find an exact description of those warnings, anybody knowns what does it mean? Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
info/warning (1, 0)
```

According to this - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html

> (int what, int extra)
>
> what - the type of info or warning. extra - an extra code, specific to
>   the info. Typically implementation dependent.

In my case:

> public static final int MEDIA_INFO_UNKNOWN Constant Value: 1
>   (0x00000001) Unspecified media player info.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with media info - the player is under the assumption that there may be timed text information associated with the media. Check the meta data associated with what you are trying to playback. You can probably safely ignore the issue in your case.

Comment: I tried to play .ogg file and get no warning messages, but I tried to play .mp3 file, and I get warning messages. In first case I with no problems can switch on/off sound channels, in second case it do not works. Brainteaser!

Comment: Also I find that .ogg file plays normally from raw res., but I tried to play .ogg file from sdcard and get the same warning and problems with channels.

Comment: what happens when you play the mp3 from res?

Comment: When I trying to play mp3 from raw res. :

info/warning (1, 0)
Info (1,0)

and the volume problem still there

Comment: May be it is important: I tried play .wav file from sdcard with AudioTrack class, and it,s method setStereoVolume works as expectes

Comment: Have you tried other test media files? That is, completely different MP3 files (from a different system) - I do suspect its the meta data in the file headers.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but: I tried to play .mp3 converted in Windows, then I converted it to .wav and in Linux converted to .mp3 - then put this file to raw res. and tested on google tv - the same result. File properies see below:

Comment: Linux file: Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 571 KiB
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Writing library                          : LAME3.99.5

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version  : Version 2
Format profile  : Layer 3
Mode  : Joint stereo
Mode extension   : MS Stereo
Bit rate mode : Variable
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Sampling rate   : 22.05 KHz
Compression mode  : Lossy
Stream size  : 571 KiB (100%)
Writing library  : LAME3.99.5